# Unable to receive request headers from jQuery AJAX in Mule

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors, mule

I have a Mule flow and I'm trying to send custom request headers using an AJAX call from html files placed on my system (html files are not on the server).

## The following code doesn't work:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

    $.ajax({

        url: "http://localhost:8081",
        crossDomain: true,
         headers: { 
            Accept : "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            "myHeader" : "myHeaderValue"
        },
        method: 'GET',
        data: { hello : "hello" }

    }).complete(function(data) { alert(data); });
});
```

I've tried using `async:false, cache:false`, content-type etc but nothing works. All I get from Mule is this:

[image]

I've added this in the Mule-flow but it still doesn't seem to work:

```
<set-property propertyName="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

I've tried hitting the same flow from Java code, Python, Postman and the same header from all sources was received in Mule with value, but AJAX it fails on.

Thanks.

Comment: Stop looking at mule. Look at the developer tools in your browser. Check that there aren't any errors (I'm surprised that it didn't complain about the lack of a allow headers response header). Use the Network tab to determine if the headers are being sent by the client in the first place.

Comment: `"Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",` — This makes no sense. You are making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content type of.

Comment: `crossDomain: true,` — This is pointless. It defaults to `true`. It's only useful if you are making a *same* origin request which is going to give an HTTP redirect to a different origin.

Comment: "I've tried hitting the same flow from Java code" — When you recreated the flow, did you remember to send [the CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests)?

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed the screenshot shows that you are looking at the preflight OPTIONS request and not the GET request. That's the problem (and it would have been quite obvious if you'd looked at the browser's Console).

Comment: Quentin is right: investigate the failure from the browser. What error(s) do you see in its console? You can't investigate this kind of issue by looking at the server only.